# Calling a ps1 from another ps1

Tags: powershell

I am calling a ps1 script from another ps1, which woks fine. Now I want to pass the  arguments to a child ps1 from parent ps1. 
For e.g.
1. master.ps1 & client.ps1 are the two scripts. 
2. client.ps1 takes two arguments, which i want to pass to it through master.ps1.

Code for the master script:

```
    Param( 
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=4)]
   [string]$clientid,
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=4)]
   [string]$clientname
            )

     Invoke-Expression "$bpath\client.ps1" "$clientid" "$clientname"
```

Error:

```
 Invoke-Expression : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test :

```
& .\YourScript.ps1 Arg1 Arg2
```

But it exists other solutions if you want to keep `Invoke-Expression` you can use :

```
Invoke-Expression -Command ".\YourScript.ps1 Arg1 Arg2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameters can be passed as array totally in a single $var or if you are passing very few params then you should prefix it with the param name. Try the below one it should work

```
Invoke-Expression "$bpath\client.ps1" -clientid $clientid -clientname $clientname
```

or you can directly pass the $var, if you prefix the "$var" it becomes a string rather than a param

```
Invoke-Expression "$bpath\client.ps1" $clientid $clientname
```